# If a US citizen in the US voluntarily works for free for Sci-Hub, is she in any trouble?

Tags: united-states

Sci-Hub gives free access to gated journal articles. In the US, Sci-Hub is in a legal grey area (if not outright illegal).

Let's say for example that a US citizen based in the US volunteers to spruce up their website. She does this completely voluntarily and receives no payment. Is she at any trouble with the law?

Answer (score 1):

Not if they do not engage in any illegal activity.

Consider a parallel case: imagine a driver who works (as a contractor or employee or gratis) for a mob boss. Providing that the driver does not become an accessory to their employer's crimes or fail to report crimes that they may be legally obliged to report and that they follow the road rules :-) then they have committed no offenc.

Comment: Possible better/more specific example: the driver picks up and drops off, to and from school, the mobster's daughter. He adheres to traffic law and reports income appropriately. Is this driver breaking law? Nope.